# Unsetting all custom Javascript objects after initialization

Tags: javascript, performance

The custom javascript of my site is namespaced, combined and minified resulting in a 12kb file of custom js. This is code for the entire site, and usually after pageload has been triggered a greater portion of it doesn't have to sit in memory.
My question:
Does a heap of custom script that only gets executed once or not at all affect a users performance? Especially if the user has multiple tabs open
I was thinking of setting `mynamespace = null` but I wouldn't know if this actually improves the users browsers performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nulling it out should trigger the garbage collector to free up some memory. Unless the system had enough stuff in memory that it was being swapped out to the disk, the user wouldn't notice a difference.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to unset JavaScript objects manually.

Because JavaScript can do ["Garbage Collection"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JSAPI_User_Guide#Garbage_collection)

**Edit:** 
You can do

```
delete window.mynamespace;
```

And the "mynamespace" will be deleted

Comment: The GC isn't going to do anything if you still have a reference to the object hanging around. Nulling out any references lets the GC know it can clean it up. Also, you can't delete things out of the global scope like that. You can only delete properties of objects (that are not the global object).